# How to set ban word for not to copy using Windows PowerShell / batch script?

Tags: powershell, command-line

I have a process folder where file/folders are copying. While files are copied, files/folder has prefix unpacking_file/folder name. I want to make a batch script/powershell which can copy files/folder from that folder but skip if file/foldername has unpack_ prefix

Comment: take a look at the parameters for the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet - >>> `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Parameter *` <<< you will find the info useful ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$source = 'C:\test\test'
$dest = 'C:\test2\'
$exclude = "unpacking_*"
```

this is how i solved the problem.